onChange Value While SetInterval Changes The Value Instantly
I have a input with type range and the value of the input is being changed by setInterval method with a 2 millisecond Interval. I can only use an eventListener to get the onChange value of the input. But the problem is that whenever the input range value is changed manually the event is triggered but the event.target.value still gets the value of the changed range value by the setInterval
<input id="element" type="range"/>

element.addEventListener('change',(event) => {
    //getting the changed value here but needed the accurate clicked value here.
    let changedValue = parseInt(event.target.value);
});

setInterval(()=>{/* some code that changes the range*/},2);



Your description of how your code works is exactly what I would expect. Your interval timer runs very frequently. Also it's not clear what you mean by "accurate clicked value"; how is the value that you currently get not accurate?

@Pointy I think they're saying that the user changes the value, the event listener runs, but instead of putting the user's value in changedValue, it's getting what the interval function set it to. The interval function shouldn't be able to interrupt the event listener.

@Barmar well yea it shouldn't, and in any working web browser I know if it definitely won't. However the code posted is really inadequate; the value is being assigned to a local variable, and we have no idea what's being done with it.

Your local variable changedValue is like a "picture" of the value taken when your input changed and.
your setInterval() cannot have the possibility to change this "picture".

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

Your question is a bit unclear. I assume that you need to accurately capture the value of the user interaction with the input range without overriding it.
To make sure that the value of the input range is accurately captured when the user manually changes it, while the value not getting overridden immediately, you can stop the interval entirely once the user interacts with the input and restart it after the interaction is complete or once change the user changes the value again.
Refer the code below for more reference:


const element = document.getElementById('element');
let intervalId;
let userInteracting = true;

function startInterval() { 
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (!userInteracting) {
      element.value = parseInt(element.value) + 1;
      if (parseInt(element.value) > element.max) {
        element.value = element.min;
      }
    }
  }, 2);
}

element.addEventListener('input', () => {
  userInteracting = true;
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});

element.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  let changedValue = parseInt(event.target.value);   // Capture the value set by the user
  console.log('User set value:', changedValue);
  element.value = changedValue;
});

startInterval(); // Start the interval initially
<html>
<head>
  <title>Input Range</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="element" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0"/>
</body>
</html>



